# Alfresco webscripts File upload directly to alfresco repository

Tags: file-upload, portlet, alfresco, cmis, web-scripting

I've been going through CMIS model in general and how to use Alfresco as CMIS repository in Alfresco Wiki and Documentation(I installed 4.2d on Windows). I am confused about many things but here is what I need to know right now:

Is there any portlet webscript i.e something I can call from my application that opens like a popup or something close available that Alfresco provides to upload files directly to Alfresco repository. If not could anyone point me to the resources from which I could build one. I would like to access repository in CMIS way preferably. There is something in alfresco/services/cmissamples/upload. Can I use that?

I saw that each of the rest URIs can be appended with alf_ticket. But the thing is URIs work even without alf_ticket. How can I make it mandatory and how can I make folders of that user only to be available for browsing or uploading files.

Any links or examples of using Alfresco as only back end repository with own ui of the application will be helpful.

I found that many of the paths in docs/wiki are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

check this two links. It should give you good pointers on CMIS and webscripts- 
http://22ecmoncloud111.blogspot.com/
http://sumantapakira.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0):

Alfresco provides file upload API to upload file. Please check following link which provides example and more details for the same.

http://basanagowdapatil.blogspot.in/2011/10/how-to-upload-file-to-alfresco-share.html
http://blog.mwrobel.eu/uploading-big-file-alfresco-web-services/